Is the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in a circular orbit constant?
I know that the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in a circular orbit is $w_0=\frac{v}{r}$ but I want to know if the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in the circle orbit is constant. I mean that derivative from x from the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in circle orbit is it zero?

I guess the two objects are orbiting about a common center of gravity so you can't have both exactly true, but the difference will be negligible for a typical man-made satellite and a planet. True?

@SpehroPefhany good job pointing that out. Negligible for typical (because gravimetry instruments do detect the variation but are not deployed on most satellites), man-made (because the effect is obvious only on geological time-frames) and a planet (because planets are by definition form a spherical homogenous body due to gravity). Not sure about polar orbit around a geoid though.

Are we assuming that the parent body is perfectly spherical; has uniform gravity, etc.? Are we ignoring the effect of other bodies, eg Sun, moon and other planets?

@MikeB this is a Space Exploration site.  Math questions are on topic, but serve as a tool, not a goal. Spherical planet in a perfect vacuum is for https://math.stackexchange.com/

@MikeB, heh, I've added drag and wind effects. Thanks for the reminder!

In the perfect, Keplerian-Newtonian spherically symmetric two-body simplification, both bodies have orbits of the same period and eccentricity about the barycenter, so angular velocity would be constant ( and if you're not in that situation, then the orbits will not be able to be truly circular)

Since the orbital speed $v = \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r}}$ of an object in a circular orbit around a body of constant standard gravitational parameter $\mu$ remains constant, the radial distance $r$ of the object in a circular orbit is also constant, and the angle between the directions of the radial distance vector $\vec{r}$ and the orbital velocity vector $\vec{v}$ is also constant for an object in a circular orbit $(\theta = 90°$)  , the angular velocity $\omega_0 = \frac{v}{r}\sin \theta$ of the object around the central body is also constant.

The speed of an object in a circular orbit remains constant but the direction of motion changes continuously.
As velocity is a vector composed of speed and direction, the velocity of an object in a circular orbit continually changes in line with the acceleration it experiences from the central object. It is continually accelerating in free fall, but by virtue of it's velocity is unable to reach the ground as it continually over shoots.

The question was about angular velocity, though?
